# Don't understand high pass filters?

Tags: filter, circuit-analysis

Consider a RC circuit functioning as a high pass filter. The transfer function is given by:

\$T(j\omega)=\frac{K}{1-j(RC/\omega)}\$

For a frequency of 0, the transfer function is 0. Which means for DC input signals, the output response is 0.

However, by modelling the circuit with a differential equation and then solving it shows that the voltage across the resistor in a RC circuit is actually a decaying exponential.

Isn't this a contradiction? The transfer function shows that the output should be 0, but the differential equation shows that it's a decaying exponential?

Comment: When you say the transfer function is "0," what do you mean? Note that it's a complex function, with magnitude and phase. Hint: what conditions are implied with phasors? Second hint: what's the difference between a transient response and a forced response?

Comment: @Shamtam By 0, I mean that for the limit of \$\omega -> 0\$, \$T(j\omega) -> 0\$. It's a complex function, but it's magnitude approaches zero in the limit right? I think your hinting at the fact that phasors only give the steady state response right?

Comment: That's correct (both, that the _magnitude_ approaches zero, and that the phasors account for steady-state). The transfer function (in terms of \$j\omega\$) only accounts for steady-state responses. If you were to deal with it in terms of the Laplace variable \$s\$, you could transform the result back into a time-domain response that has the steady-state and transient responses accounted for, pending boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4):

The key point is that it is 0 in *steady state*. That is, as \$t\rightarrow\infty\$, \$V_{out}\rightarrow0\$. When you take the differential equation, you're looking at output voltage with respect to time.

Let's try taking a look at an example of this system.
I'm going to simplify \$K=1\$ and \$RC=1\$. Then, we are left with:
$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\left(j\omega\right)=T\left(j\omega\right)=\frac{1}{1-j/\omega}
$$
To simplify our calculations, let's change the form of it and replace \$j\omega\$ with \$s\$. Then, we get:
$$
T\left(s\right)=\frac{s}{s+1}
$$
Taking the step response of this (that is, \$V_{out}\$ when the input \$V_{in}=u\left(t\right)\$ where \$u\left(t\right)\$ is the Heaviside step function) we get this:
[image]

Note that this is in *time domain*, and in steady state, our output voltage is zero. The bode plot comes out as you'd expect (first order high-pass filter):
[image]